# TeeChart library doesn't render for Windows embedded 7

Tags: delphi, teechart, windows-embedded

I have an application that was compiled with Delphi and links to  TeeChart libraries.  It plots just fine on the Desktop version of Windows 7, but doen't plot at all on Windows 7 Standard embedded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's really no information here that we can use to try and help you. You're going to need to provide a lot more detail, and since Delphi 7 is a decade old, there's no way to guarantee apps built with it will work on Win7 embedded. Have you made any effort to debug the app to find out why it might not be working? D7 supports remote debugging quite well.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see anything about Delphi 7, only Windows 7. In fact, I don't see a Delphi version anywhere.

Comment: @Jerry, you're right. I could have sworn I saw Delphi 7; must have read it wrong. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Did you contact Steema? They should be your first port of call. If you did already contact them then include their advice in the question.

Comment: As David said. Steema have helped me a lot over the years.

Comment: Someone from Steema answered my last TeeChart question on here. However, I doubt they'll be able to help you. I doubt they have Win7Embedded. There is nothing you can't do in Windows Embedded provided you (a) have capable drivers and (b) build your windows embedded platform's profile out with a whole giant pile of "optional" components that are all standard in regular windows. I actually think what you want is the MicrosoftWindows Embedded forums. Perhaps TeeChart is using GDI+ for instance and that's not working.

Comment: You might want to post more details on Windows Embedded; What's your hardware platform, what options and hardware are there, and how you handled that in your Windows Embedded platform builder toolset.  Because it's bound to be a video issue related to your unique Win7 embedded platform build (ICE and IBW are the current tools).

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Windows Embedded Standard 7 in a visrtual machine and the Tee9New demo in the "TeeChart compiled demo" [here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl) seems to work without problems on it.

Please, check your project is compiled with runtime packages if you are running it in a machine without TeeChart installed.

Yeray Alonso,

Steema Software